# Unexporting enviromental variable

Tags: shell, unix

I have a variable

```
pathname="xxx"
```

I have set it as an enviroment variable using

```
export pathname="xxx"
```

How do I "reverse" it and make the variable not exported?

Comment: Bash Refernece Manual entry for [export](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-export)

Comment: Which shell? As far as I know, you can't do this in POSIX shell.

Comment: im not working with  POSIX shell

Comment: Ok, it's not POSIX. Which shell are you using? (POSIX is a standard, not a shell. Several shells, probably including the one you're using, conform to that standard.) If you're not sure which shell you're using, does `echo $BASH_VERSION` print something? If not, try `echo $KSH_VERSION` and `echo $ZSH_VERSION`.

Comment: `echo $0` should print the name of the shell you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` you can use `typeset` (or its synonym `declare`) to remove the export attribute.

```
$ export foo=3
$ bash -c 'echo $foo'
3
$ typeset +x foo
$ bash -c 'echo $foo'

$
```

(The same command works in `zsh` and `ksh`. You can use `declare` in either `bash` or `zsh`, but not `ksh`, and it is probably more common to see it used in practice.)

As far as I know, there is no way to remove the export attribute in POSIX shell. (`dash` is a prominent example of a shell which does not provide an extension such as `declare`.) You would need to save the value in a temporary value, unset the original, then reset the original:

```
$ export foo=3
$ tmp=$foo
$ unset foo
$ foo=$tmp
$ echo "$foo"
3
$ sh -c 'echo $foo'

$
```

(`dash`, at least, explicitly documents that the only way to remove the export attribute is to unset it.)

Comment: I've never seen `typeset` in my life. Please suggest the alternatives which are actually used IRL ;)

Comment: I originally used `declare`, but switched to `typeset` to simplify the discussion for the three "major" shells. `declare` is not supported by `ksh`.

Comment: That makes sense then. It still feels wrong though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93609/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-karoly-horvath).