# Does bash have a way to un-export a variable without unsetting it?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, environment

Is it possible to `export` a variable in Bash, then later un-export it, without unsetting it entirely? I.e. have it still available to the current shell, but not to sub-processes.

You can always do this, but it's ugly (and I'm curious):

```
export FOO

#...

_FOO=$FOO
unset FOO
FOO=$_FOO
```

Answers about other shells also accepted.

Comment: The [`dash` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) explicitly states: *"the only way to un-export a variable is to unset it."*

Comment: Regarding other shells: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33395668/1126841

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
export -n FOO
```

From `help export`:

> Options:
>
> - `-f`    refer to shell functions
> - `-n`    remove the export property from each NAME
> - `-p`    display a list of all exported variables and functions